# Who knows about the SQL problem on 2079 June 6?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I heard that from a youtube video. The video is ***`Brief History of the Future - 245 Years in 11 Minutes`***. **In the video only says there will be a problem with SQL servers on 2079 June 6**. I was interested in this. I searched this on the internet, but I didn't find anything. If you have any information about this, please share

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming at all...

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow ..

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2079-06-06'))` is `65535`. The problem is that this is not a problem: `DATETIME`s aren't stored internally as 16-bit values. (And if they were, the problem would occur sooner because T-SQL's integer types are signed, not unsigned.) If there is an issue due to overflow somewhere, it must be pretty subtle -- or else not related directly to SQL Server. The worst "problem" SQL Server suffers from is the Y10K problem: `SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, '99991231'))` will fail.

Comment: One would hope that any future version of SQL Server being used in a time even close to Y10K would have resolved that problem (and if someone is still using SQL Server 2017 then you have to wonder why they are using software that is 8,000 years old :) ).

Comment: @larnu - 'Five-digit years are already a problem today for many forward-looking analysis programs (e.g. software that examines proposals for the long-term handling of nuclear waste). ' - source wikipedia

Comment: @Cato: I put "problem" in quotes because, while what's *true*, most people with that "problem" would probably also not require something like an exact date -- unless, say, you want to declare your radioactive waste safe on April Fools and not a day earlier. Storing offsets in some big time unit that will comfortably fit a 32-bit int will be good enough, long before you'd need to move to `DECIMAL` or `FLOAT`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Wikipedia article [Time formatting and storage bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_formatting_and_storage_bugs#Year_2079):

> Programs that store dates as the number of days since an arbitrary date (or epoch) are vulnerable to roll-over or wrap-around effects if the values are not wide enough to allow the date values to span a large enough time range expected for the application. Signed 16-bit binary values roll over after 32,768 (2^15) days from the epoch date, producing negative values. Some mainframe systems experienced software failures because they had encoded dates as the number of days since 1 January 1900, which produced unexpected negative day numbers on the roll-over date of 18 September 1989. Similarly, unsigned 16-bit binary days counts overflow after 65,536 (2^16) days, which are truncated to zero values. For software using an epoch of 1 January 1900, **this will occur on 6 June 2079**.

Comment: Not that SQL Server appears to suffer this as `datetime` is more than happy to accept `CONVERT(datetime, '20790607')` (which is day `65536`) and even `SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '21790607')`. So the claim that SQL Server specifically will suffer the problem appears to be incorrect. `date` and `datetime2` is more than happy to store dates 1,000's of years in the future, so that isn't an issue either.

Comment: @Larnu I don't think the claim is about Microsoft SQL Server, but about some (generic) SQL server. (I would be very surprised if this is still a problem in any major SQL server software today, much more in 2079.)

Comment: I'll probably have retired, I'll be 113.  It seems unlikely that this would happen, unless a date is stored as an int and an application manipulates the values in unsigned ints, then it could roll over to zero and pass a zero to SQL server